# How Can I Save URLs in Firebase Realtime Database in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application I use following code to save some values in Firebase Realtime database and it is working fine.

```
private FirebaseClient _firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("MY_FIREBASE_URL_HERE");
await _firebaseClient.Child("CHILD_1").Child("CHILD_2").PutAsync("SOME_STRING_DATA_HERE");
```

If I add a URL string in `PutAsync` function, it throws an exception saying **`Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value`**. How Can I resolve this issue because I need to store a URL in Firebase.

Comment: The code you now show won't throw the error you have, and if you add the URL as a string it should also work fine. So most likely the problem comes from how you pass the URL. Please show the [minimal, exact/complete code needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the URL is like this `await _firebaseClient.Child("CHILD_1").Child("CHILD_2").PutAsync("https://test.something.com/V0/some_text?key=some_long_key_here");`

Comment: This error occurs when the fields you are trying to send to Firebase contain invalid characters. Read this [blog](https://zapier.com/help/doc/common-problems-firebase#invalid-data-error-couldnt-parse-json-object) may help.